# Why is the element that I add to an array replace the one that I added before?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm making a calorie counter, and I ran into this problem, that every time I add an item(with the number of calories and its name) it ends up replacing the one before I added before. I don't know why this happens and I would greatly appreciate if you could help me. I've tried a lot of times doing different stuff and testing why it doesn't work and I couldn't figure it out.

This is the app.js file.

```
// Item Controller
const ItemController = function(){
  data = {
    items : [
            {name: "Hamburguer", id: 0, calories: 1000},
            {name: "Pasta", id: 1, calories: 700},
            {name: "Apple", id: 2, calories: 70}],
 
    currentItem : false
  }
  return {
    getItems: function(){
      return data.items;
    },
    logItems: function(){
      console.log(data.items); 
    },
    addItems: function(name, calories){
      const item = new Object({name: name, id: 4, calories:calories});
      this.getItems().push(item);
      UIController().clearItems();
      UIController().displayItems(this.getItems());
      this.logItems();
    }
  }
}
 
// UI controller
const UIController = function() {
  return {
    displayItems: function(items) {
      items.forEach(function (item) {
        itemList = document.getElementById("item-list");
        itemList.innerHTML += `
        <li class="collection-item" id="item-0">
          <strong>${item.name}: </strong><em>${item.calories} calories</em>
          <a href="#" class="secondary-content">
          <i class="edit-item fa fa-pencil">
          </i>
          </a>
        </li>
        `;
      })
    },
    clearItems: function () {
      itemList = document.getElementById("item-list");
      itemList.innerHTML = "";
    }
  }
}
 
// App controller
const App = function(){
  return {
    startApp: function() {
      UIController().displayItems(ItemController().getItems());
    },
  }
}
 
addTaskBtn = document.querySelector(".add-btn");

addTaskBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  inputNameField = document.getElementById("item-name");
  inputCalorieField = document.getElementById("item-calories");

  ItemController().addItems(inputNameField.value, inputCalorieField.value);

  e.preventDefault();
});

App().startApp();
```

Here's the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Tricalorie | Meal & Calorie Tracker</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Nav Bar -->
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper blue">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo center">
          Tracalorie
        </a>
        <ul class="right">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="clear-btn btn blue lighten-3">
              Clear All
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <br>

  <div class="container">
    <!-- Form Card -->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
        <span class="card-title">
          Add Meal / Food Item
        </span>
        <form class="col">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input type="text" id="item-name" placeholder="Add item">
              <label for="item-name">Meal</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input type="text" id="item-calories" placeholder="Add calories">
              <label for="item-calories">Calories</label>
            </div>
            <button class="add-btn btn blue darken-3"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            Add Meal</button>
            <!-- <button class="update-btn btn orange"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
            Update Meal</button>
            <button class="delete-btn btn red"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
            Delete Meal</button> -->
            <button class="back-btn btn grey pull-right"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i>
            Back</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Calorie Count -->
    <h3 class="center-align">Total Calories: <span class="total-calories">
      0
    </span></h3>

    <!-- Item list -->
    <ul id="item-list" class="collection">
      <!-- <li class="collection-item" id="item-0">
        <strong>Steak Dinner: </strong><em>1200 Calories</em>
        <a href="#" class="secondary-content">
        <i class="edit-item fa fa-pencil">
        </i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-item" id="item-0">
        <strong>Cookie: </strong><em>400 Calories</em>
        <a href="#" class="secondary-content">
        <i class="edit-item fa fa-pencil">
        </i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-item" id="item-0">
        <strong>Eggs: </strong><em>300 Calories</em>
        <a href="#" class="secondary-content">
        <i class="edit-item fa fa-pencil">
        </i>
        </a>
      </li> -->
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Every time you do `ItemController()` it creates a new, clean version of the data.

Comment: How can I avoid this?

Comment: Don't call it multiple times. `const items = ItemController()` and use that variable every time.

Comment: You've hard-coded `id` to `4`?
`addItems: function(name, calories){
      const item = new Object({name: name, id: 4, calories:calories});`